# how many times the numbers repeat inside an array, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, iterator, numbers

id like to know how i can check how many times the numbers i have stored in an array repeat them selves!
that's the code i have:

```
const int max = 15;
int a[max] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 0, 8, 7, 1, 2 }; //Input array
map<int, int> m;

for (int i = 0; i<max; i++)
{
    m[a[i]]++;  //Increment the value of key for counting occurances
}

int mostNumTimes =0;
int number = -999; //-999 represents invalid number
map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin();
    for (; it != m.end(); it++)  //Find the number which occurred 
    {                           //most number of times
        if (it->second > mostNumTimes)
        {
            mostNumTimes = it->second;
            number = it->first;
        }
    }

if (number != -999)   //Print number and number of times it occurred
{
    cout << "Number: " << number << endl;
    cout << "Number of times occured: " << mostNumTimes << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Input array is empty" << endl;
}
```

This code finds and prints the most repeated number and how many times repeated itself inside the array, 
i'd to change it so it shows the times any number repeates itself in the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a loop like this

```
for ( const auto &p : m )
{
   std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Or you can decorate it.:)

```
for ( const auto &p : m )
{
   std::cout << "Number " << p.first 
             << " occurs in the array " << p.second 
             << " times" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterator for `std::map` points to a key-value *pair*. You can access the key using its *first* member and value using *second*. This is how you can print all map entries:

```
map<int, int>::const_iterator it = m.begin();  // add const for safety
for ( ; it != m.end(); ++it)  //print all entries
{
    cout << "Number: " << (*it).first << endl;
    cout << "Number of times occured: " << (*it).second << endl;
}
```

You can also use auto:

```
for( const auto &entry : m) 
{
    cout << entry.first << '\t' << entry.second << endl;
}
```